# Animation For loop image does not show

Tags: ios, xcode, loops, for-loop, jquery-animate

I've downloaded animated bonfire from the internet. My image sequence is "*.png" and I can't get it work. It keeps looping to the end. It does not show image. How come I can't animate this code? What did I do wrong?

```
        UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:screenx.frame];
        int j;
        int i;

        for (j = 1, i = 0; i < 28; i =1)
        {
            NSLog( @"%i.png", i);
            campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                            [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",i]], nil];
        }
        // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
        campFireView.animationDuration = .15;
        // repeat the annimation forever
        campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
        // start animatinganimationRepeatCount:1];

        [campFireView startAnimating];

        // add the animation view to the main window 
        [self.view addSubview:campFireView]; 
        [campFireView release];
```

Comment: why don't you use the `"%d.png"` formatter instead of `"%i.png"`? and what is the weird mix of variables `i` and `j` in the header of `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call:

```
        campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",i]], nil];
```

You are setting the `animationImages` to a one-item array. What you probably meant to do instead:

```
    NSMutableArray *animationImages = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (i = 0; i < 28; i++)
    {
        [animationImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",i]]];
    }

    campfireView.animationImages = animationImages;
```

Also - I don't know what was going on with your `for` loop but I fixed it.

Comment: [animationImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",i]]];
     code showed up SIGABRT on XCODE 4.5

Comment: @user1692698 Well your `for` loop was pretty broken so was only executing once anyhow, so corrected my part of the answer. Is `imageNamed` returning a nil image for some value of `i`?

Comment: @user1692698 ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

When u r looping then providing one image every time to animationImages

```
NSMutableArray *arrImgs = [NSMutableArray array];

for (i = 0; i < 28; i++)
    {
        [arrImgs addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",i]]];
    }

campfireView.animationImages  = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrImgs];
```